# Ubuntu 16.04 crashing PowerEdge 1950 Gen II

Tags: boot, kernel, raid

I am faced with a strange situation whereby just past the Ubuntu (Ubuntu or Ubuntu Advanced Options) boot screen I get an intermittent crash that sends the BIOS of the Dell PowerEdge 1950 Gen II into fatal i/o errors and reboots the system.

The errors I keep getting are:

- E1422 CPU Machine chk
- E1715 I/O Fatal Error

Troubleshooting So Far

1. Checked the logs through iDrac but these are not much of a help.
2. Performed Dell full hardware diagnostics and got no errors
3. Physically checked for any lose connections within the server, but everything is as it should.
4. Checked that all the firmware is updated.
5. Cleared NVRAM

The problem seems that just past the boot, the kernel crashes when loading the megaraid but its hard to fish this out as the server reboots instantaneously.

I have also run journalctl, systemctl and dmesg and no errors were reported or logged on the few occasions that the system booted.

Cycled through a myriad of different SAS drives (15k and 10k rpms) and also ran Ubuntu 16.04 on a USB.

Last step I took was to try another distro which worked perfectly, hence by rule of thumb, the problem seems to be within the kernel of Ubuntu.

**Edit 1**

Further to hardware troubleshooting above.

I have stripped down all the parts within the 1950, cleaned and reapplied thermal grease to the E5335 CPUs and all the onboard coolers and that of the RAID controller.

Any ideas as what I can do to troubleshoot the kernel that is crashing just at boot?